# Postgres - pgloader - Column names are converted to lower case in PostgreSQL by default

Tags: postgresql, pgloader

I have inherited a large MySQL database and want to move data to postgresql db. In this case when I run below command to dump data from MySQL, facing the issue that column names are converted to lower case in PostgreSQL by default., But expected is PostgreSQL to keep column names in upper or mixed case what exactly from MySQL db.

```
 pgloader mysql://root:password@$localhost/accessdatabase \
 postgresql://postgres:password@postgres/accessdatabase
```

Having an issue with column names being converted to lower case during migration from MySQL to Postgres.

Is there a query I can run migrate what same as MySQL db to postgresql db?

Comment: did you try this  - quote identifiers

When this option is listed, pgloader quotes all MySQL identifiers so that their case is respected. Note that you will then have to do the same thing in your application code queries. https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/mysql.html - do you have a reason for wishing to preserve case in view of the downsides.

Comment: *Is there a query I can run migrate what same as MySQL db to postgresql db?* Query? no. If you want to preserve the columns names case-sensitivity then you must edit your dump file and enclose all columns names with double quote chars. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: I'm trying to migrate a legacy MySQL database into Postgres using Pgloader. I'm trying to think of a relatively robust way to find a way to convert the existing SQL queries to work with the new database with the least amount of manual modifications.

One of the big pain points is that the old database is written in mixed case, and so are all the SQL queries. If you query SELECT Table.Column Postgres will treat that as select table.column so it doesn't work out of the box. Converting the database tables and columns to lowercase is not an option. @P.Salmon

Comment: Of course one option would be to manually add quotes around each identifier in all of the queries eg `SELECT "Table"."Column", but I'm wondering if there's another way that I haven't thought of, like a Postgres module or something.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: *Any help would be highly appreciated!* Do nothing, agree with lowercased identifiers. This will make all names lowercased - in both structure and your queries. If you'll store the names case then you'd do this in all your queries which is hard work.

Comment: I am trying to migrate a large portion of mysql database to postgres database that has a mixed case of column names. But the data is same. What is a good way to do this? All I can think of is using pg_dump and then manually changing the column names and table names in the dump file but there is a lot of data to work through and that way would also be very error prone.

Comment: Is the only skill set you can call on mysql/postgresql ? If the dump is a text file with end of line characters and possibly line feeds, I feel pretty certain that in the vast unix arsenal there are  functions (grep/sed?) that might do or vba or python which can convert upper to lower.  Really it;s just read a file>>write a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--with "quote identifiers"` option, that instructs `pgloader` to quote all identifiers, thus preserving their original case from MySQL.

```
pgloader mysql://root:password@localhost/accessdatabase \
         postgresql://postgres:password@postgres/accessdatabase \
         --with "quote identifiers"
```